# Spring MVC testing, JNDI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jndi, spring-test

I would like to bind an existing data source to a JNDI name for my tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml",
        "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/test-datasource.xml" })
public class SimulatorTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createContext() throws NamingException {
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
        builder.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB", dataSource);
        builder.activate();
    }
...
```

This seems to work but as soon as my code (i.e. EclipseLink) tries to look up this JNDI name, it fails:

```
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: SimpleNamingContext does not support [javax.naming.Name]
```

I've looked at the source code and it really doesn't: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContext.java#L225-L293

How can I create a context so EclipseLink does not fail to look up the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue. Just avoid using JNDI during tests, at least that's also what many people suggest.

In my code, I was creating an `EntityManagerFactory` manually that looks up the JNDI string defined in the persistence.xml. This was failing during test time due to missing JNDI.

Now, I let Spring create the EntityManagerFactory for me and let Spring pick the DataSource.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">INFO</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

The advantage of not defining the JNDI name of the data source in the `persistence.xml` but in the spring configuration, is that Spring can overwrite the `dataSource` bean during testing - so now JNDI lookup, no failing tests.